# Will a managed switch that supports VLAN's in it's default configuration pass VLAN tagged frames?

Tags: vlan

I have a managed switch that I need to introduce between a number of servers that are operating in a VLAN tagged with the VLAN 100.

I have an older SMC TigerSwitch 10/100 that I need to put between these machines so that I can introduce another server into the mix.

Will the default config with a VLAN 1 still pass all tagged frames?

Second question: will a standard unmanaged switch pass VLAN frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what your network looks like and this depends on the scenario. I will give a few options:

```
Server <--Vlan 100> Switch <Vlan 100--> Server
to 
Server <--Vlan 100> Switch <Vlan 100--> New Switch <---> Server
```

In this case the Switch doesn't need any configuration for the vlan

```
Server <--Vlan 100> Switch <-trunk-> Switch <Vlan 100--> Server
to 
Server <--Vlan 100> Switch <-trunk-> Switch <Vlan 100--> Server
                           <-trunk-> New Switch <Vlan 100--> New Server
```

In this case you need to setup the uplink port on the new switch as a trunk port (to get it to accept the vlan tagged traffic, otherwise most switches will drop vlan tagged frames) and the ports towards the new servers need to be tagged with the correct vlan.